# How to navigate to a div when clicking an anchor tag after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<a href="#goto">Link 1</a>

<div id="goto">DIV</div>
```

On clicking the anchor tag my page reloads and shows a new div(id=goto), which was hidden before clicking, at the bottom of the page. I want to navigate to the div(id=goto), which is visible now, after the page reload.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by hidden it has the attribute hidden you can check for the attribute and navigate to the div by using `window.location.hash` like in my snippet. Please verify if that is what you expected.

```js
if (!document.querySelector('#goto').hasAttribute('hidden')) {
            window.location.hash = '#goto';
            console.log("found");
}
```

```html
<a href="#goto">Link 1</a>

<div id="goto">DIV</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `href` to point for current directory by using `./`

```
<a href="./#goto">Link 1</a>
```